# How to colve SSL SYSCALL error: Bad file descriptor with celery?

Tags: django, django-celery, celery-task

I had an issue running celery tasks. celery was down for unkonwn issue. I tried to use django dbshell to check the table contains the task results:

```
SELECT * FROM django_celery_results_taskresult LIMIT 1;
```

Here is the query output:

I found an error related to SSL and the same errors populated over and over on sentry issue. Is there a way to get rid of it?